# "Timeout was reached" error when opening file with gvim

Tags: 12.04, gvim

I am new to linux Ubuntu 12.04. Every time I open a file with the `gvim` editor it gives me following warning:

```
** (gvim:4620): WARNING **: Unable to create Ubuntu Menu Proxy: Timeout was reached
```

What should I do to solve this problem?